# Apache Camel: Can I use @Produce without specifying the endpoint uri in the annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, apache-camel, jms

In the camel [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html), it is mentioned that we can inject the ProducerTemplate using the @Produce annotation as shown below.

```
 @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;
```

I am wondering if it is possible not to specify the uri in the annotation and pass the uri to the producer in its sendBody method, like below, so that I can use this in a Util class to produce to any endpoint?

```
public class JmsProducerUtils {
    @Produce
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    public void publishMessageToEndpoint(String endpoint, String message) {

        producer.sendBody(endpoint, message);
    }
}
```

Are there any concerns, to be aware of, in using it like this?

Comment: adding as a comment since it indirectly answers your question. You could make the utility CamelContextAware and then use the CamelContext to get a Producer. Then call the sendBody as you are in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no worries, it should definitely work - you can write a simple unit test to verify it - but unless your URIs are dynamically formed in runtime I would suggest using the approach they mention in their documentation e.g. have an interface:

```
@InOnly
public class JmsProducer {
  void publish(String message);
}
```

and then inject it in your class like so:

```
public class Foo {
  @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
  private JmsProducer fooProducer;

  @Produce(uri = "activemq:bar")
  private JmsProducer barProducer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, create a URI that starts with "stub:" (ex "stub:noUri")

From https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/stub-component.html

*The Stub component provides a simple way to stub out any physical endpoints while in development or testing, allowing you for example to run a route without needing to actually connect to a specific SMTP or Http endpoint. Just add stub: in front of any endpoint URI to stub out the endpoint.*